# How to get past locked password door in Level 13 of Old Nua maze?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I'm at level 13 on the Old Nua maze and there is a door that I can't pass.
It requires a password that a ghost is supposed to give me but the ghost doesn't want to speak to me.

I don't want to use console cheats as recommended elsewhere.

I also don't speak Engwathian, but I heard that I'll learn it later in the game and I'm not sure if it is required here.

**How can I unlock this door in a legitimate way?**

EDIT: I now speak the language that the ghost does. He does give me the password but the door still wont open. BUG??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a walkthrough on what you have to do in order to open the door.  Depending on where you are quest-wise in the game it isn't as simple as just speaking to a ghost and then it working.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Arqade. While links and videos in answers are just fine, you should really make an effort to at least summarize the things in those core to the answer. Otherwise, if the video ever gets taken down, your answer will become useless.

Answer (score 2):

You have to speak the same language as the ghost. You must talk to the ghost mid east on the map and get the password. Then talk to the one south-west/central on the map to learn its been reversed. Tell the door you are there to kill his friends and you are an enemy and it will open.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the ghost from the Eastern North gives you the password and a button in the middle of the room can be switched but I get no button and maybe I answered wrong with the ghost. http://guides.gamepressure.com/pillarsofeternity/guide.asp?ID=29967

Comment: that guide is awesome but also not complete. i have it bookmarked. doesnt explain much. says ghost will tell you. but the ghost doesnt understand me. I have now completed the quest where i learn the old language so i will go back and try to speak to the ghost in hopes of it understanding me now.